# Efficient way of converting RNA sequence to protein in Java, and arrayoutofbound error

Tags: java, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

Below is my highly inefficient and non working code for converting RNA sequence to Protein:

```
String translation(String temp)
{
    char[] result;
    int k=temp.length();
    int i=0;
    int z=0;
    char[] pro=new char[100];
    result=new char[temp.length()];
    result = temp.toCharArray();
    while(i<k-3)
    {
     char[] store;
     store=new char[1];
     store[0]=result[i];
     String tempstore1 = new String(store);
     store[0]=result[i+1];
     String tempstore2 = new String(store);
     store[0]=result[i+2];
     String tempstore3 = new String(store);
     String storefinal=tempstore1+tempstore2+tempstore3;

     if(storefinal.matches("UUU")||storefinal.matches("UUC"))
     {
         pro[z]='F';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("UUA")||storefinal.matches("UUG")||storefinal.matches("CUU")||storefinal.matches("CUC")||storefinal.matches("CUA")||storefinal.matches("CUA")||storefinal.matches("CUG"))
     {
         pro[z]='L';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("AUU")||storefinal.matches("AUC")||storefinal.matches("AUA"))
     {
         pro[z]='I';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("AUG"))
     {
         pro[z]='M';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("GUU")||storefinal.matches("GUC")||storefinal.matches("GUA")||storefinal.matches("GUG"))
     {
         pro[z]='V';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("UCU")||storefinal.matches("UCC")||storefinal.matches("UCA")||storefinal.matches("UCG"))
     {
         pro[z]='S';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("AGA")||storefinal.matches("AGG"))
     {
         pro[z]='R';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("AGU")||storefinal.matches("AGC"))
     {
         pro[z]='S';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("UGG"))
     {
         pro[z]='W';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("UGU")||storefinal.matches("UGC"))
     {
         pro[z]='C';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("GAA")||storefinal.matches("GAG"))
     {
         pro[z]='E';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("GAU")||storefinal.matches("GAC"))
     {
         pro[z]='D';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("AAA")||storefinal.matches("AAG"))
     {
         pro[z]='K';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("AAU")||storefinal.matches("AAC"))
     {
         pro[z]='N';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("CAA")||storefinal.matches("CAG"))
     {
         pro[z]='Q';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("CAU")||storefinal.matches("CAC"))
     {
         pro[z]='H';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("UAU")||storefinal.matches("UAC"))
     {
         pro[z]='Y';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("CCG")||storefinal.matches("CCA")||storefinal.matches("CCC")||storefinal.matches("CCU"))
     {
         pro[z]='P';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("ACG")||storefinal.matches("ACA")||storefinal.matches("ACC")||storefinal.matches("ACU"))
     {
         pro[z]='T';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("GCG")||storefinal.matches("GCA")||storefinal.matches("GCC")||storefinal.matches("GCU"))
     {
         pro[z]='A';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("CGG")||storefinal.matches("CGA")||storefinal.matches("CGC")||storefinal.matches("CGU"))
     {
         pro[z]='R';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("GGG")||storefinal.matches("GGA")||storefinal.matches("GGC")||storefinal.matches("GGU"))
     {
         pro[z]='G';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     if(storefinal.matches("UAG")||storefinal.matches("UAA")||storefinal.matches("UGA"))
     {
         pro[z]='.';
         z++;
         continue;
     }
     i++;
    }    
    String finalreturn = new String(pro);
 return finalreturn;
}
```

Now there are two problems associated with it:

1. It is not working(Array out of bound exception)
2. I cannot figure out how to manage the flanking unassociated redundant codes, which don't code for anything.

Is there any way I can use regex to solve this problem? (I mean like in perl)
Edit : whole exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
at JSATS2.transcriplation.translation(transcriplation.java:197)
at JSATS2.TabExp.jButton7ActionPerformed(TabExp.java:835)
at JSATS2.TabExp.access$1100(TabExp.java:14)
at JSATS2.TabExp$12.actionPerformed(TabExp.java:599)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Well, if you want the error diagnosed you'd better provide the full exception information.

Comment: Why not use [BioJava](http://biojava.org/wiki/Main_Page). Then it is as simple as `ProteinSequence protein = new RNASequence("GAUC").getProteinSequence();`

Comment: I can use BioJava, but then again it will defeat my purpose of making a stand alone application.

Comment: Why do you say it's not working? do you receive an error or the output is not the expected?

Comment: @Siddharth Then copy the code of BioJava for your "stand alone application", (keep in mind the copy rights).

Comment: give as an input string for temp? is it bigger than 100 characters?

Comment: And where is line 197??

Comment: With standalone I mean that I shouldn't include any external libraries except for one provided by default, although I can, if needed. (More or less it's like an assignment, without any constraint as such)

Comment: @Konstantinos, both, error and well, as a collateral, not the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To increase speed I would use a static Map for all available codons

Use a StringBuilder to build your finalresult

Be sure that your String input is a multiple of 3

Be sure that every triplet corresponds to a valid codon

```
private static final Map<String, Character> codonsMap;
static
{
    codonsMap = new HashMap<String, Character>();
    codonsMap.put("UUU", 'F');
    codonsMap.put("UUC", 'F');
    codonsMap.put("UUA", 'L');
    //and so on for all codons
}

//be sure that length of temp is a multiple of 3 and that every 3 characters correspond to a valid codon
public String translation(String temp)
{
    //Use StringBuilder for adding Characters, it is by far faster than adding chars to a mutable String
    StringBuilder finalreturn = new StringBuilder();
    String codon;       
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length() - 2; i++) {
        codon = temp.substring(i, i+3);
        finalreturn.append(codonsMap.get(codon));
    }
    return finalreturn.toString();
}
```

Comment: If you are not sure about your input (if it is well formatted - multiple of 3 - valid codons) you have of course to add the additional checks

Comment: Right, as for the checks, I was thinking of a sliding window, where the first valid codon will start the translation process.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can build the substring in one go with the substring() method. Then, you can build the output with a StringBuilder. Finally, you can use a switch statement, which makes the code more readable. The result looks like this:

```
static String translation (String rna) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < rna.length() - 2; i++) {
        String triplet = rna.substring(i, i+3);

        switch (triplet) {
        case "UUU":
        case "UUC":
            sb.append("F");
            break;
        case "UUA":
        case "UUG":
        case "CUU":
        case "CUC":
        case "CUA":
        case "CUG":
            sb.append("L");
            break;
        case "AUU":
        case "AUC":
        case "AUA":
            sb.append("I");
            break;
        case "AUG":
            sb.append("M");
            break;
        case "GUU":
        case "GUC":
        case "GUA":
        case "GUG":
            sb.append("V");
            break;
            // and so on
        default:
            // do nothing;
        }           
    }       

    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(translation("UUCGUGAUU"));
}
```

Also, I am not sure if incrementing i by one unit is really what you want since I don't know anything in this area, maybe it should be incremented by 3 if a translation is made ?

As a final remark, this question would possibly be more at home on the Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: Indeed. Java 7 has been around for a while, though, so it is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: Latin has been around for a while, but not many people actually speak it.  Java 6 still has a strong installed base in the corporate world where the cost of upgrading includes significant amounts of regression testing.

Comment: When you make a condescending remark, at least get it right. Latin is *no longer* spoken by many people, the exact opposite of a language *not yet* spoken by many people.

Comment: I fully agree with your assertion about condescending remarks, you should definitely get it right.  Unfortunately, the opposite of "no longer" is "still" and the opposite of "not yet" is "currently" or "already".

Comment: You are right, of course. A natural language that has been around for millenia, spoken by a decreasing number of people, is a great analogy for a very recent version of a computer language that is being used by an increasing number of people. I see it now, they are the exact same thing. I thank you infinitely for your words of wisdom and shall henceforth refer to Java 7 as the Latin of computer programming.

Comment: Conatibus, tibi tandem punctum posse.

Comment: Back in the day, this might have been enough to give my Latin teacher a heart attack. Seriously, how did you get it so wrong ? Did you throw dices to pick the words in declension and conjugation tables ? Or maybe use Google translate from English to Swahili to Hebrew to Afrikaans to Latin ? I assume you mean something like *Operis, intelligere tandem potes*, which I doubt in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is because you do not increase your the index variable i. Therefore you keep repeating for the first three characters.

The underlying reason is that when you use "continue" you continue with the next iteration of the while loop. And because you only increment i after all possible matches, you will never reach this statement. Therefore try putting the increment just before the big if-then-else statement.

Also, you might want to increment by 3, and loop while i is smaller than or equal to k -3.

A suggestion to reduce some of the unnessecary code would be:

```
public static String translation(String temp) {
    int i = 0;
    String result = "";
    while (i <= temp.length() - 3) {
    String triplet = temp.substring(i,i+=3);
        if (triplet.equals("UUU") || triplet.equals("UUC"))
            result += 'F';
        if (triplet.equals("UUA") || triplet.equals("UUG")
                || triplet.equals("CUU") || triplet.equals("CUC")
                || triplet.equals("CUA") || triplet.equals("CUA")
                || triplet.equals("CUG"))
            result += 'L';
        if (triplet.equals("AUU") || triplet.equals("AUC")
                || triplet.equals("AUA"))
            result += 'I';
        if (triplet.equals("AUG"))
            result += 'M';
        if (triplet.equals("GUU") || triplet.equals("GUC")
                || triplet.equals("GUA") || triplet.equals("GUG"))
            result += 'V';
        if (triplet.equals("UCU") || triplet.equals("UCC")
                || triplet.equals("UCA") || triplet.equals("UCG"))
            result += 'S';
        if (triplet.equals("AGA") || triplet.equals("AGG"))
            result += 'R';
        if (triplet.equals("AGU") || triplet.equals("AGC"))
            result += 'S';
        if (triplet.equals("UGG"))
            result += 'W';
        if (triplet.equals("UGU") || triplet.equals("UGC"))
            result += 'C';
        if (triplet.equals("GAA") || triplet.equals("GAG"))
            result += 'E';
        if (triplet.equals("GAU") || triplet.equals("GAC"))
            result += 'D';
        if (triplet.equals("AAA") || triplet.equals("AAG"))
            result += 'K';
        if (triplet.equals("AAU") || triplet.equals("AAC"))
            result += 'N';
        if (triplet.equals("CAA") || triplet.equals("CAG"))
            result += 'Q';
        if (triplet.equals("CAU") || triplet.equals("CAC"))
            result += 'H';
        if (triplet.equals("UAU") || triplet.equals("UAC"))
            result += 'Y';
        if (triplet.equals("CCG") || triplet.equals("CCA")
                || triplet.equals("CCC") || triplet.equals("CCU"))
            result += 'P';
        if (triplet.equals("ACG") || triplet.equals("ACA")
                || triplet.equals("ACC") || triplet.equals("ACU"))
            result += 'T';
        if (triplet.equals("GCG") || triplet.equals("GCA")
                || triplet.equals("GCC") || triplet.equals("GCU"))
            result += 'A';
        if (triplet.equals("CGG") || triplet.equals("CGA")
                || triplet.equals("CGC") || triplet.equals("CGU"))
            result += 'R';
        if (triplet.equals("GGG") || triplet.equals("GGA")
                || triplet.equals("GGC") || triplet.equals("GGU"))
            result += 'G';
        if (triplet.equals("UAG") || triplet.equals("UAA")
                || triplet.equals("UGA"))
            result += '.';
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I understand the reason for out of bound now, sort of, and there is no error, thanks.(Will keep in mind about the continue statement)